# Can't get Image to Centre after changing width to auto and max height

Tags: css

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/151785559320

Hi. So I've been messing around with my eBay listing page for the last couple of hours trying to solve this.

First of all I wanted to change the max height rather than the width, which I sorted with this code:

```
 img.img-responsive.col-xs-12 {
 width: auto !important;
 max-height: 650px !important;
 }
```

But then it was effecting my thumbnails, so I used this code to prevent it screwing my thumbnails up:

```
 img.img-responsive.col-xs-12.img-thumbnail {
 width: 100% !important;
 max-height: auto !important;
 }
```

Everything looks all right, except now my images align left instead of centre. Ever since I put the width to auto.

The thing is, I'm using WidgetChimp.com for the CSS generation, so I can only enter custom arbitrary code on top, not edit anything in the main CSS file generated on that eBay listing page.

Any help please.

NOTE: Before using the code in the first block, it was centering.

Comment: "this code:" and..:) where your code?

Comment: 1. Please show us your code. 2. What is your eBay link related to?

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, I pressed enter to enter a tag CSS, and it submitted my question.

Comment: It might help to tell us exactly which images you would like to be centered. I'm assuming that you mean the `<img />` element inside of `.gal-image.center-block`?

Comment: Just to add, the 2nd code isn't really important, it's the first code. I was just trying to explain what I was doing. Also the 2nd code, I want to know if it's right, it looks like the thumbnails are working correctly, expect maybe in Safari iOS browser, so don't know whether they are the right settings.

Comment: http://s11.postimg.org/fjzn8vpr7/image.png

Comment: I'm uber n00b at CSS, so I've been trying to work this out through trial and error. So I can't tell you which one via it's name, just point to it like I did in the picture.

Comment: It should be noted before the code:

    img.img-responsive.col-xs-12 {
     width: auto !important;
     max-height: 650px !important;
     }

It was centering